# Why Hive returns this result?

Tags: hive

An interesting question. There is a table `test.test` which comprises 11 columns (all `string`) and **only one row** of data:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+--+
| c1  | c2  | c3  | c4  | c5  | c6  | c7  | c8  | c9  | c10  | c11  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+--+
| 1   | 2   | 3   | 4   | 5   | 6   | 7   | 8   | 9   | 10   | 11   |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+--+
```

If I execute the query in **`Hive`**:

```
    select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11 
    from test 
    where c1='1' 
    sort by c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11 
    limit 10;
```

It returns:

```
1       2       11      3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10
```

The content of columns changed...

The query returns normal result via `Spark-SQL`. I also tried the following queries in `Hive`:

```
select..from..where..sort by..
select..from..sort by..limit..
select..from..where..limit..
```

and all of them return normal result.

Could anyone please explain what results in this wired result？

Comment: Are you sure there is only one row in this table? Or does LIMIT give you 1 row?

Comment: @KamilG. yes  only one row. I just tried `limit 10` and it returned the same result.

Comment: Check `set hive.compute.query.using.stats=false; select count(*)` without limit. Count(*) can use statisticks and it may be stale. but select * will return more rows